# Android, SubView or what?

Tags: android

How in android create SubView or what, like this (This is Gallery from Android 4.2)

[image: SubView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html). It's a nice example, it uses `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

a LinearLayout which has the tower as background and a button with image in the bottom...

Answer (score 1):

The FrameLayout is used for overlapping views or a single view.